# Selenium firefox driver takes 30-40 seconds to launch firefox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am developing tests using selenium webdriver 2.3 and initializing the browsers as below:

```
if (testBrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("Mozilla")) 
{
 dvr = new FirefoxDriver();
  System.out.println("Invoking firefox in your system");
}
else if (testBrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
{
 File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/IEDriverServer.exe"); 
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
 dvr = new InternetExplorerDriver();
 } else if (testBrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) 
{
   File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/chromedriver.exe"); 
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
   dvr = new ChromeDriver();

}
```

Evertime firefox is launched it takes about 30-40 seconds, while launching the rest of the browsers like chrome or safari e.t.c launch within seconds.

Though I tried the solution as suggested in the blog below but didn't work for me:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/a2fNfF-mD_E

Will really appreciate if anyone has a workaround for this.

Comment: have observed this since 22, 23, 24

Comment: Just making sure before proceeding with further debugging, Have you checked this part from the link you have pasted? 

Alan is Right! It was taking 2;30 Seconds to launch Firefox for me, After disabling unused Network adapters(located in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections), Problem gets resolved, now now its launching in 10 secs to me.

Comment: @HemChe Yes! I have already disabled two adapters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some profile settings for FF which I using with my test cases on python.
As I know it makes better performance:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override', user_agent)
        # Paint delay off
        profile.set_preference('nglayout.initialpaint.delay', 0)
        # Tabs animation
        profile.set_preference('browser.tabs.animate', False)
        # Gif animation off
        profile.set_preference('image.animation_mode', 'none')
        # Tabs memory off
        profile.set_preference('browser.sessionhistory.max_total_viewer', 1)
        profile.set_preference('browser.sessionhistory.max_entries', 3)
        profile.set_preference('browser.sessionhistory.max_total_viewers', 1)
        profile.set_preference('browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo', 0)
        # Asynchronous requests to the server
        profile.set_preference('network.http.pipelining', True)
        profile.set_preference('network.http.pipelining.maxrequests', 8)
        # Cache enabled
        profile.set_preference('browser.cache.memory.enable', True)
        profile.set_preference('browser.cache.disk.enable', True)
        # Autosuggests
        profile.set_preference('browser.search.suggest.enabled', False)
        # Formfills
        profile.set_preference('browser.formfill.enable', False)
        # scan downloads
        profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone', False)
        # no bookmarks backup
        profile.set_preference('browser.bookmarks.max_backups', 0)
```

Try it with Java syntax.